# I'm new to coding and was trying to fix these errors but did not understand how to do so

Tags: java

The assignment is to find area and circumference of a circle and area and volume of a sphere. I have no idea how to fix the errors and have tried.

code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class RoundThingsDriver
    {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
        double area, circumference, volume, surfaceArea, radius;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 
        System.out.println("Enter a radius: ");
        radius = scan.nextDouble();

        area = roundThings.calcAreaCircle(radius);
        outPut("circle", "circumference", radius, area);

       circumference = roundThings.calcCircumCircle(radius);
       outPut("sphere", "surface area", radius, surfaceArea);

       volume = roundThings.calcVolumeSphere(radius);
       outPut("sphere", "volume", radius, volume);

       scan.close();
     }
      public static void outPut(String shapeName, String typeValue, double radiusInputted, double 
     actualValue);
     {
       System.out.println("The"+typeValue+"of a"+shapeName+"with a radius 
       of"+radiusInputted+"is"+actualValue);
      }
    }
     public class roundThings
   {
        public static double calcAreaCircle(double radius)
     {

       double area = radius * radius * Math.PI;

       return area; 

     }
     public static double calcCircumCircle(double radius)
     {
       double circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius;

       return circumference;
     }
     public static double calcAreaSphere(double radius)
     {
       double surfaceArea = 4 * Math.PI * radius * radius;

       return surfaceArea;
     }
     public static double calcVolumeSphere(double radius)
     {
       double Volume = (4/3) * Math.PI * (radius*radius*radius);

       return Volume;
     }
   }
```

ERRORS:

```
 javac -classpath .:/run_dir/junit-4.12.jar:target/dependency/* -d . Main.java roundThings.java
Main.java:4: error: class RoundThingsDriver is public, should be declared in a file named RoundThingsDriver.java
public class RoundThingsDriver
       ^
Main.java:25: error: missing method body, or declare abstract
  public static void outPut(String shapeName, String typeValue, double radiusInputted, double actualValue);
                     ^
Main.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println("The"+typeValue+"of a"+shapeName+"with a radius of"+radiusInputted+"is"+actualValue);
                             ^
  symbol:   variable typeValue
  location: class RoundThingsDriver
Main.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println("The"+typeValue+"of a"+shapeName+"with a radius of"+radiusInputted+"is"+actualValue);
                                              ^
  symbol:   variable shapeName
  location: class RoundThingsDriver
Main.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println("The"+typeValue+"of a"+shapeName+"with a radius of"+radiusInputted+"is"+actualValue);
                                                                           ^
  symbol:   variable radiusInputted
  location: class RoundThingsDriver
Main.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println("The"+typeValue+"of a"+shapeName+"with a radius of"+radiusInputted+"is"+actualValue);
                                                                                               ^
  symbol:   variable actualValue
  location: class RoundThingsDriver
6 errors
compiler exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In order for this to compile, you need to put the code in a file called `RoundThingsDriver.java`. That's what the error message told you to do. *class RoundThingsDriver is public, should be declared in a file named RoundThingsDriver.java*
2. At the end of the header of the `outPut` method, you have a semicolon. That shouldn't be used here. The opening curly brace needs to immediately follow the method header. The only thing allowed in between is whitespace.